# Como llamar datos a combobox desde una hoja especifica VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

soy nuevo y estoy intentado desarrollar un formulario para una captura de datos, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el Userform me llama los datos en el rango de la hoja activa. Lo que me gustaria modificar es que los datos los llame de una hoja en especifico para poder ejecutar el Userform desde cualquier hoja.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código

Dim area As Boolean

```
For i = 2 To [a65536].End(xlUp).Row
    
    area = False
    
    For a = 0 To Me.cmbarea.ListCount - 1
    
        If CStr(Range("a" & i).Value = cmbarea.List(a)) Then
        
            area = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
    
    If area = False Then
        Me.cmbarea.AddItem Range("a" & i).Value
    End If

Next i
```

[image: Aqui el formulario funciona perfectamente y obtengo los datos]

[image: bueno, al cambiar la hoja activa ya no me devuelve nada]

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Por defecto, si solo llamas al objeto `Range` usará el de la hoja activa. Si quieres llamar a rangos de otras hojas, tienes que usar el objeto Worksheet combinado con Range. Por ejemplo, `Range("A1") es celda A1 de la hoja activa, pero ``Worksheets("Otra hoja").Range("A1")` es la celda A1 pero de la hoja que se llama `Otra Hoja` independientemente de si es la activa o no.